# SQL Server : how to insert into 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This seems like a really simple answer, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around how I should accomplish this...

I've got two different tables:

1. Campaign
2. Campaign_Customer

Where `dbo.Campaign` is all of the details of the campaign, and `dbo.Campaign_Customer` is basically a summary table that contains the `CampaignID`, `CustomerID`, `CreationDate`, and `DeletionDate` (if there is one)

So, when I go to insert a new record into my `dbo.Campaign` table, I need to be able to use the `CampaignID` that it generates to create a record into my `dbo.Campaign_Customer` table.

I know this is possible, but I don't know the proper way to do so. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have 2 separate insert statements within transaction. If your campaign Id is identity column you can get its value using scope_identity function in select after first insert

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO dbo.Campain (x, y, z) VALUES (x, y, z)
DECLARE @id int
SELECT @id = scope_identity()

INSERT INTO dbo.Campaign_Customer (CampaignId, x, y) VALUES (@id, x, y)
COMMIT
```

Comment: So do I put this transaction inside of a stored procedure?

Comment: It probably would be best if you are using stored procedures for your CRUD but it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a trigger to do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Campaign_Trigger] on dbo.Campaign
AFTER INSERT AS
INSERT INTO dbo.Campaign_Customer (CampaignId, x, y)
VALUES (t.CampaignID, t.x, t.y)
FROM Inserted t
```